# How to setting up angular 2 in visual studio 2013?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2, angular-cli

How to setting up angular 2 in visual studio 2013, there is no external web tool is available. 
Already I followed the [Angular2 Quick Start](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) to create a project in VS 2013, but failed to get work.

Does tsconfig.json is supported in VS 2013?

Any help or reference link would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest you to use VSCode to develop your angular application. Every month VSCode team improving VSCode for great development experience.

If you still want to use Visual studio then I will suggest you to use VS 2015 or higher. VS 2013 don't have proper tooling form npm, grunt and all other things which you will heavily use in Angular app. As your project will grow you will not feel comfortable with 2013 version.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can technically work with an Angular project in Visual Studio 2013, your experience will be mediocre compared to Visual Studio 2015,2017 or Visual Studio Code.

That is because Angular uses TypeScript 2.0 or above. The last version of TypeScript shipped for Visual Studio 2013 is version 1.8 according to that [answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11214).

So to avoid errors during project compilation you need to disable the internal TypeScript compiler using the `TypeScriptCompileBlocked` setting. The TS 1.0 which was shipped initially with VS2013 doesn't understand that setting and doesn't support `tsconfig.json`. So you need to install the TS 1.8 tooling in VS2103. Add `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to the project file.

Install the latest version of the TypeScript compiler as an npm package and set up an external tool like gulp or grunt or npm to compile your project. You can call that tool during compilation of your project with the standard MSBuild. I recommend you install the Angular CLI and run the `npm start` command manually from a separate Command Prompt window. This way you will enjoy your files recompiled and reloaded in the browser automatically on every save.

`tsconfig.json` will be supported by the external TypeScript compiler installed by you.

IntelliSense in the code editor will not recognize the latest features of TypeScript.